# Liquibase and Terraform best practices

Tags: database, terraform, liquibase

We are implementing Liquibase on a Terraform project, and I want to know how do you manage the database users and grants creation.

We think that the best option is create the database, users and grants with Terraform, and make liquibase only take care of creating the necessary tables for the project.

Is this considered a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. Anything dealing with the internals of the database should be handled by Liquibase.

And added bosuns is that you can repurpose your Liquibase Changelog for dev so they are using a database that matches the production config. And, that right there, is gonna save a lot of "works on my machine" back and forth.

Let us know how we can help: https://www.liquibase.org/community/community-supporters